# How to host my website developed using sql and asp.net locally?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2014-express

I have developed An Online Examination System project using Visual Studio for web 2013 IDE, using asp.net and SQL SERVER 2014 and CSS. Now I want to host this in one of the 50 systems which acts as a server and remaining should be able to access this page using Server's IP address.

The small version of IIS which is installed with my Visual Studio is helping me to host my website locally.

Now my question is... How can I achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install IIS to host the web application.
I don't know what kind of operating system you have so I'll post the steps for Windows 8.1.

Go to **Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows Features On or Off**

From there check Internet Information Services (as shown in the image below)

[image: Install IIS]

After install open **Internet Information Services Manager** click on the `Default Web Site` and on the right panel click `Basic Settings`.

[image: Configure web site in IIS]

In the `Physical Path` box enter the path to where your application resides and click Ok.

Now, make sure that the login `IIS_USR` has access to the database and you're set.

For a more detailed list of steps and more configuration options please check the [article](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/scenario-build-an-aspnet-website-on-iis/configure-an-asp-net-website-on-iis) on IIS site.

Comment: Thats indeed a very explanatory one. Let me try this solution. I'm using windows 7. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what version of Windows is installed on the server, but following the detailed instructions [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/674930/Configuring-IIS-ASP-NET-and-SQL-Server) should help you out. After that, just make sure the machines can see each other via local network.